# Datepicker resets time to UTC

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, momentjs, utc

I have a simple custom Angular DatePickerDirective.
Problem is - when I click into it, and then out, value is being converted to UTC.
How to prevent that?

```
import moment = require('moment');

class DatePickerDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    constructor() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: ($scope: any, $element: any, attrs: any, ngModel: any): void => {

                var defaultOptions: any = {
                    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                    autoclose: true
                };

                $element.datepicker(angular.extend({}, defaultOptions, $scope.options));

                ngModel.$formatters.unshift((val: any) => {
                    var date: Date = moment(val).toDate();
                    var picker: any = $element.data('datepicker');
                    picker.dates.replace([date]);
                    picker.viewDate = date;
                    picker.fill();
                    return date;
                });

                ngModel.$parsers.unshift((val: any) => {
                    return moment(val);
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
export = DatePickerDirective;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this directive

```js
 app.directive('datepickerLocaldate', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: ['ngModel'],
            link: link
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
            var ngModelController = ctrls[0];

            // called with a JavaScript Date object when picked from the datepicker
            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                // undo the timezone adjustment we did during the formatting
                viewValue.setMinutes(viewValue.getMinutes() - viewValue.getTimezoneOffset());
                // we just want a local date in ISO format
                return viewValue.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
            });

            // called with a 'yyyy-mm-dd' string to format
            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                if (!modelValue) {
                    return undefined;
                }
                // date constructor will apply timezone deviations from UTC (i.e. if locale is behind UTC 'dt' will be one day behind)
                var dt = new Date(modelValue);
                // 'undo' the timezone offset again (so we end up on the original date again)
                dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset());
                return dt;
            });
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: Yes, I saw this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623872/angular-ui-datepicker-adjusting-for-timezone?rq=1) and original gist (https://gist.github.com/weberste/354a3f0a9ea58e0ea0de) - unforutunately didn't work for me somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to convert from UTC to ISO.  Just add the date-to-iso attribute to your input element.

```
 myApp.directive("dateToIso", DateToIso);
 function DateToIso () {
    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (datepickerValue) {
           var dt = new Date(datepickerValue);
           dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset());
           return dt;
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: linkFunction
    };
}
```