# Angular UI datepicker is getting wrong date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui

I'm writing an app in [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) and I'm using [Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/) together with it. I have a datepicker that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-required="true"
       name="targetDate"
       uib-datepicker-popup="MMMM yyyy" 
       min-mode="'month'" 
       datepicker-mode="'month'"
       is-open="opened" 
       ng-click="openCalendar()"
       close-on-date-selection="true"
       show-button-bar="false" 
       min-date="today"
       ng-model="targetDate"  />
```

The problem is that when I select, for example, July 2016, the value that I have in my targetDate model is "2016-06-30T21:00:00.000Z", which is exactly 3 hours before July 2016. I think that this has something to do with my local time and UTC time, because I live in a region where the local time is +2 hours UTC but I don't know why this happens and how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to convert UTC to Local time by Using MomentJs library  http://momentjs.com/docs/. if you already Know momentjs read abt this for Quick http://www.digitoffee.com/programming/get-local-time-utc-using-moment-js/94/

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/  for  using from start

Comment: this issue has been mentioned before here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623872/angular-ui-datepicker-adjusting-for-timezone

Comment: doesn't work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this thread - [GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2072)

Try to change your machine timezone as the Date obj chooses the local time of your machine by default.

Or try to parse the Date object to milliseconds by getTime() if its worth and add 10800000 ms which is 3 hr to the date model.

So your new date model will be something you chosen(in milliseconds) + 10800000 = Desired UTC date.

Comment: Are you really suggesting that the user change their local time just because the app wants to display something in UTC time?

Comment: For temporary solution, convert the date object model to milliseconds and add 10800000 (3hrs)

Comment: So your new date model will be something you chosen(in milliseconds) + 10800000 = Desired UTC date.

Comment: I don't recommend it. For temporary sake only. Please suggest us a permanent solution sir!

Answer (score 0):

This actually solved my problem and here's my code:

```
    service.ConvertDateToJSONDate = function (dateInput) {
        if (dateInput === null || dateInput === undefined) {
            return null;
        }
        //return "\/Date(" + dateInput.getTime().toString() + ")\/";
        return "\/Date(" + (dateInput.getTime() + 10800000).toString() + ")\/";
    };
```

Usage: service.ConvertDateToJSONDate(SelectedDateObjectToBeConverted);

Answer (score 0):

If you're using just the date (don't care about time) you may want to convert it to local midnight at the earliest opportunity. Needing a constructor is one good reason to use a class instead of an interface for a model, IMHO. Then you have this mess out of the way in one place, instead of littering your code with conversions.

```
export class MyModel {

  // The runtime can still assign a string to Date, despite static type.
  date: Date;

  constructor(data: MyModel) {
    Object.assign(this, data);

    // Convert string e.g. '2008-12-25' to Date at local midnight.
    if (typeof this.date === 'string') {
      const localDate = new Date(this.date);
      this.date = new Date(localDate.getTime() + localDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
      console.log(this.date);
    }
  }
}
```