# AngularJS date received at server is one day behind

Tags: angularjs, datetime, timezone, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using a [persian-datepicker](https://github.com/AminRahimi/angular-bootstrap-persian-datepicker) in my project, when I pick a date by this component the value stored in `modelValue` is something like this: `Mon Apr 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)`, but when I send this value to server using `$http.post`, this value gets transformed to this: `2017-04-09T19:30:00.000Z` and server side code interpret this value as yesterday, does any one know what should I do in this situation? I am pretty confused by this behavior.

Comment: it seems your server is in `GMT` and hence transforms your datetime into it. If you see the time, it is exactly `4:30` less

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used `persian-datepicker` before, but I faced this issue on `angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker`which I assume is related.  `angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker` uses the **JavaScript Date** object to calculate the dates hence it serializes to a UTC datetime string.

In the native `angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker` you can do:

```
ng-model-options="{timezone: 'utc'}"
```

To get a datepicker without timezone calculation.

According to this [persian-datepicker](https://github.com/AminRahimi/angular-bootstrap-persian-datepicker/issues/27) issue, it seems `ng-model-options`is supported too. If it is so then you can try:

```
<input
 uib-datepicker-popup
 ng-model="modelValue"
 ng-model-options="{timezone: 'utc'}">
```

Refer to this [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623872/angular-ui-datepicker-adjusting-for-timezone) for ideas.

**Edit: Convert the dates manually**

If the above is not supported in  `persian-datepicker`, then try this method.
After you convert your date in `modelValue`to a **date object** e.g

```
var date = new Date(modelValue);
```

Then you can do as follows:

```
var formattedDate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) +  '-' + date.getDate();
```

This will give you a date like `'2017-4-10'`without any conversion.However, if you want to use UTC conversion do it like:

```
var formattedDate2 = date.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1) +  '-' + date.getUTCDate();
```

Do this just before you send the date to your server and send `formattedDate`or `formattedDate2`to the server. It seems that before you invoke `$http.post`the following operation is done, to convert your date to JSON -

```
JSON.stringify(date)
```

which yields :`2017-04-09T19:30:00.000Z`that in turn is sent to the server.

Comment: It think the issues says that time-zone is not supported.